# update seperate component based on select value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql, nuxt.js

I have a blogs page that has includes two different components `filter` and `card`

```
<template>
  <div>

    <div v-if='$apollo.loading'>Fetching data...</div>
    
    <div v-else>
      <FilterComponent :categories='categories' />

      <Card :blogs='blogs' />
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import blogsGQL from '../graphql/blog/blog.graphql'
import categoriesGQL from '../graphql/category/category.graphql'
import Card from '~/components/Blog/Card'
import FilterComponent from '~/components/Blog/FilterComponent'

export default {
  name: 'Blogs',
  components: { FilterComponent, Card },
  layout: 'blog',

  apollo: {
    blogs: {
      query: blogsGQL,
      prefetch: true
    },
    categories: {
      query: categoriesGQL,
      prefetch: true
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Inside of my filterComponent I have a select dropdown filled by categories coming from the database, when I select on of these categories a graphql query fires that fetches new blog posts filted by category_id

```
<template>
  <div class='w-full bg-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-900 py-10'>
    <div class='container mx-auto px-6 flex items-start justify-center'>

      <form id='filter' @submit.prevent>
        <div class='mt-16 flex flex-col  w-full'>
          <select id='category'
                  v-model.number='selected'
                  class='dark:border-gray-700 pl-3 py-3 shadow-sm rounded text-sm focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-700 bg-transparent placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400'
          >
            <option value='0' selected>Choose category</option>
            <option v-for='category in categories' :key='category.id' :value='category.id'>
              {{ category.category }}
            </option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import blogPostByCategoryId from '~/graphql/blog/blogByCategoryId.graphql'

export default {
  name: 'FilterComponent',

  props: {
    categories: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  },

  data() {
    return {
      selected: 0
    }
  },

  apollo: {
    blogPostByCategoryId: {
      query: blogPostByCategoryId,
      variables() {
        return {
          category_id: this.selected
        }
      },
      skip() {
        return !this.selected
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

But how do I update the card component with the new data I received from my filter component? is it possible to just pass the `blogPostByCategoryId` result back into the card component somehow ?

EDIT:

I managed to get some pieces working,  I currently have a `index.js`  file inside of my `store`  directory of nuxt this file contains the following code:

```
import blogsGQL from '~/graphql/blog/blog.graphql'

export const state = () => ({
  blogs: []
})


export const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit({ commit }, context) {
    const client = context.app.apolloProvider.defaultClient

    const response = await client.query({ query: blogsGQL })

    commit('setBlogs', response.data.blogs)
  }
}

export const mutations = {
  setBlogs(state, blogs) {
    state.blogs.push(blogs)
  },

  filter(state, categoryId) {
    state.blogs.map(blog => blog.category_id === categoryId)
  }
}
```

I query my graphql api and put all posts inside of my state, then in my parent component I pass down the data to my card component like so:

```
      <Card :blogs='blogs' />


  computed: {
    blogs() {
      return this.$store.state.blogs
    }
  },
```

Now, I'm not sure if I'm having a brainfart but when trying to loop over the array inside of my card component like this:

```
        <div v-for='blog in blogs'
```

All I get is blank space? I console logged the `blogs` array and the data is inside of it.

EDIT 2 :

So I fixed my previous problem, had to use `state.blogs.push(...blogs)` to get it working.

I also changed my file a bit after reading some docs I now use a getter to get the filterblogs :

```
export const getters = {
  filterdBlogs: state => (categoryId) => {
    return state.blogs.filter(blog => blog.category_id === categoryId)
  }
}
```

I call this method on the apollo update method inside of my filterComponent :

```
      update(data) {
        const id = data.blogByCategoryId[0].category_id

        this.$store.getters.filterdBlogs(id)
      }
```

This seems to work, console logging the filterdblogs method returns correct items but my card component is not being updated.

EDIT 3

so I changed the card component instead of passing it through props I do this now

// card component

```
<template>
  <div class='w-full bg-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-900 py-10'>
    <div class='container mx-auto px-6 flex justify-center'>
      <div class='w-full'>
        <div v-for='blog in blogs'
             :key='blog.id'
             class='flex flex-row  mx-auto bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 justify-center shadow rounded'>
          <div class='w-full lg:w-1/3 px-12 flex flex-col items-center py-10'>
            <div class='w-24 h-24 mb-3 p-2 rounded-full bg-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-700 flex items-center justify-center'>
              <img class='w-full h-full overflow-hidden object-cover rounded-full'
                   :src='`https://tuk-cdn.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/components/grid_cards/gc_${blog.id}.png`'
                   alt='avatar' />
            </div>
            <h2 class='text-gray-800 dark:text-gray-100 text-xl tracking-normal font-medium mb-1'>{{ blog.title }}</h2>
            <p class='text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-100 text-sm tracking-normal font-normal mb-8 text-center w-10/12'>
              {{ blog.big_text }}</p>
            <p class='text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-100 text-sm tracking-normal font-normal mb-8 text-center w-10/12'>
              {{ blog.small_text }}</p>
            <div class='flex items-start'>
              <div class='mx-6 border-l border-r'>
                <NuxtLink :to='`blog/${blog.slug}`'>
                  <button type='submit'
                          class='group relative w-full flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500'>
                    Read more
                  </button>
                </NuxtLink>
              </div>
              <div class='mx-4 border-l border-r'>
                <h2
                  class='group relative w-full flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white text-black'>
                  Posted on {{ blog.created_at | formatDate }}
                </h2>
              </div>
              <div class='mx-4 border-l border-r'>
                <h2
                  class='group relative w-full flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white text-black'>
                  Updated on {{ blog.updated_at | formatDate }}

                </h2>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Card code block end -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Card',

  filters: {
    formatDate: (dateStr) =>
      Intl.DateTimeFormat('us-EN').format(new Date(dateStr))
  },

  computed: {
    blogs() {
      return this.$store.state.blogs
    }
  }

}
</script>
```

Now when I select a value on my dropdown menu the state is not being updated;

// dropdown component

```
<template>
  <div class='w-full bg-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-900 py-10'>
    <div class='container mx-auto px-6 flex items-start justify-center'>

      <form id='filter' @submit.prevent>
        <div class='mt-16 flex flex-col  w-full'>
          <select id='category'
                  v-model.number='selected'
                  class='dark:border-gray-700 pl-3 py-3 shadow-sm rounded text-sm focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-700 bg-transparent placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400'
          >
            <option value='0' selected>Choose category</option>
            <option v-for='category in categories' :key='category.id' :value='category.id'>
              {{ category.category }}
            </option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import blogPostByCategoryId from '~/graphql/blog/blogByCategoryId.graphql'

export default {
  name: 'FilterComponent',

  props: {
    categories: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  },

  data() {
    return {
      selected: 0
    }
  },

  apollo: {
    blogPostByCategoryId: {
      query: blogPostByCategoryId,
      variables() {
        return {
          category_id: this.selected
        }
      },
      skip() {
        return !this.selected
      },
      update(data) {
        const id = data.blogByCategoryId[0].category_id

        this.$store.commit('filter', {
          categoryId: id
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

my filter method looks like this :

```
export const mutations = {
  filter(state, payload) {
    return state.blogs.filter(blog => blog.category_id === payload.categoryId)
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use Vuex, dispatch new data from `filter component` and in `card component` it will reactive updated

Comment: You wrote like this `<div v-for='(blog, key) in blogs' :key="key">{{blog}}</div>` or realy `<div v-for='blog in blogs'` ?

Comment: Managed to fix the issue, had to use `state.blogs.push(...blogs)` to get it working, but now my component is not refreshing after selecting a filter, will edit again for you

Comment: Share you Card component where data is not updated

Comment: For the first `<Card :blogs='blogs' />` why you throw Vuex state throught props ?

Comment: You must use `this.$store.state.blogs` in Card component, whithout props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do mistake when mutate Vuex state. Correct format of mutation:

```
export const state = () => ({
     blogs: [],
     search: null //if you want multiselect you must use array [] with ids
})

export const getters = {
  filterBlog(state, payload) {
    return state.search ? state.blogs.filter(blog => +blog.category_id === +state.search) : state.blogs
  }
}

export const mutations = {
  setBlogs(state, blogs) {
    state.blogs.push(blogs)
  },
  search(state, id) {
     state.search = id
  }
}
```

Card component:

```
 <div v-for='blog in blogs'>

  computed: {
    blogs() {
      return this.$store.getters.filterBlog
    }
  }
```

Dropdown component:

```
update(data) {
     const id = data.blogByCategoryId[0].category_id

     this.$store.commit('search', id)
 }
```

In Vuex, you change the current state directly, rather than returning a new one like in Redux Reducer.

Comment: Hey, seems like elements are being removed from the array? e.g. if I filter by category_id 1 items are filtered correctly, but if I chose category_id 2 after, no items are inside of the array. even though I added one with category_id 2

Comment: If you want filtering state for template you must do it in getter, if you want update state you must do it in mutations

Comment: i edited answer

Comment: edited, with dropdown filter